# Initialize variables in Ruby - best practice

Tags: ruby, string, variables

I'm learning Ruby and I've got a question regarding best practice. If I want to initialize a new, empty string, what method is best:

```
variable = ""
variable = String.new
variable = String("")
variable = String(nil)
```

Is there any difference?

Comment: Most common is `variable = ''`. But this being Ruby, you don't need to initialize variables in most situations.

Comment: Why '' and not ""?

Comment: Either is ok, but most Rubyists use single quotes unless they need to use string interpolation. See the Ruby style guide [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide), which describes both options. (Click to the page then search for "quotes".)

Comment: I expect you may have the same question about arrays and hashes, so let's look at those too. `str = ''`, `arr = []`, `h = {}` are the most common ways of initializing empty strings, arrays and hashes, respectively. I am not aware of any potentially useful alternatives for strings and arrays, but it is often convenient to create a hash with a *default value* given as an argument of `new` or the value returned by a block. (See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-c-new))....

Comment: ...A common example of the former is often called a *counting hash*, used like so: `[1,2,5,1,2].each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 } #=> {1=>2, 2=>2, 5=>1}`. A typical example of using a block is grouping words by length: `['cat', 'skunk', 'ox', 'dog', 'tiger'].each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |w,h| h[w.size] << w } #=> {3=>["cat", "dog"], 5=>["skunk", "tiger"], 2=>["ox"]}`. I realize that, being new to Ruby, you probably will not immediately understand these expressions, but in time you will. My point is that there are useful options when creating empty hashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
variable = ""
```

or

```
variable = ''
```

Would be the most common.

Now comes the important question, why do you need it?

Ruby newcomers often write some code like :

```
words = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']

variable = ''

for word in words do
  variable += word
end

puts variable
```

before learning that they could just use :

```
puts words.join
```

Taking a look at the available [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) and [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html) methods might help you.